# Castle Windsor WcfFacility error. forgot to register component?

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I am trying to get Castle Windsor to create my WCF using WcfFacility. I followed this tutorial. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426770/Dependency-Injection-in-WCF-using-Castle-Windsor but it doesn't seem to work for me. I am getting the following error.

**Could not find a component with name ActionService.ServiceImplementations.ActionWebService, did you forget to register it?**

The way my application is structured is the following.

One project for the webservice (only svc files without code behind, web.config and global.asax)

Second Project for the Contracts and Implementations. This is where IActionWebService  and ActionWebservice resides.

I have the reference of the latter into the first one.

This is my global asax.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    IWindsorContainer container;
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
            .Register(
            Component.For<IAuthService>().ImplementedBy<AuthService>(),
            Component.For<IUserRepository>().ImplementedBy<UserRepository>(),
            Component.For<IActionWebService>().ImplementedBy<ActionWebService>().Named("ActionWebService")
            );
    }
```

And this is my svc file.

```
    <%@ ServiceHost 
Language="C#" 
Debug="true" 
Service="ActionService.ServiceImplementations.ActionWebService"
Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration" %>
```

I already went thru other questions in here and other blogs but their solutions haven't been of any help for me :(.

Anyone that can point where the error could be happening?

EDIT
I attached a Watch Window capture. There you can see that all objects seems to be loaded. But it doesn't resolve them.

[image: Here you can see that the actual objects are loaded in the container. It just doesn't resolve them]

Comment: Nevermind guys, found the reason. In my service declaration i have the whole assembly+namespace+class and that wasn't matching my named property in the global.asax... seems like i am still under the influence of turkey and sweet mashed potatoes... :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error

to solve it in the string paramter for the registration, I put it with the complete namespace something like this.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>().Register(
          Component.For<IActivityLogsRepository>().ImplementedBy<ActivityLogsRepository>(),
            Component.For<IActivityLogsService>().ImplementedBy<ActivityLogsService>()
                .Named("Company.ServiceImplementation.ActivityLogsService"),
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Hi Kmilo. Yes, if you look at my comment, i self explained the error. Thank you for your response thou.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same issue, this is because our project's output dll name was changed while the svc file markup code is still referring old dll name:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="[Namespace.ClassName],[DllName]" Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration" %>
```